# UIViewController can not view UITableViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, tableview

I have 2 views. The first one is the main UIViewController and the second is UITableViewController and it has my data to display.

So I put a button on the first one and I want to go from my UIViewController to mytableviewcontroller. But when write this code my app crashes what's wrong in my code?

The error: thread 1 program received signal sigabrt

```
    -(IBAction) displayTableView:(id) sender{
 myTableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] 
                        initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" 
                        bundle:nil];

 [[self view] addSubview:myTableViewController.view];  // thread 1 program received signal sigabrt


}
```

thanks advanced

Comment: can you add crash logs? Is it xib? what do you have in the viewDidLoad of these classes?

Comment: this is in my UITableViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    databaseName = @"my.db";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
 databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
 
 [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
 
 [self readAnimalsFromDatabase];
     
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`addSubview` does not retain your `myTableViewController`, so the app crashes.
```

You should use property for myTableViewController, or, even better, put your controllers in UINavigationController

Comment: how use property for myTableViewController?? or how put my controllers in UINavigationController

Answer (score 0):

This should work. There is some other problem. From the code you have posted, your view controller name is: **MyTableViewController**, and the nib name you are giving is: **TableViewController**. Usually, when you create a view controller with an xib, it has the same name. If you have created the xib separately, make sure that you have connected the view outlet in the interface builder. That should work.

Comment: I have connected the view outlet in the interface builder.

Comment: i have put my controllers in UINavigationController very nice thanks all